# zoomIn effect (Animate.css) has quick flash of the element before it disappears and zooms in

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image that I wanted to zoomIn on page refresh.  The image is located at the very top of the page.  When you open the page from another webpage the image is there for a split second, disappears and then zooms in as the element is supposed to.  How do I get the appearance for the split second to not show at all and just have the image zoomIn from 0 opacity?

Here is my code for this project:

```css
@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.zoomIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
  animation-name: zoomIn;
}
```

```html
<div class="Header-Image-Container rellax">
  <img src="images/Calibrator_Logo_Text_NoBackground.png" alt="Header Picture" class="Header-Image 
    wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="3s" />
</div>
```

Here is a link to the actual site where I am having the issue: [www.calibrator.ca/TestSite](http://www.calibrator.ca/TestSite).  I am just trying to have the image start from a 0 opacity and then zoom to a 1.  To me it looks as if the css code would accomplish this but when it renders in chrome and firefox it has this flash of the image before it disappears.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any delay at all between the painting of the loaded image and the start of the animation (likely), the image will be visible for a short amount of time, causing the flash you see. A solution is to style the image with `visibility: hidden` at the start, and then set `visibility` to `visible` as the first frame of your animation (or use JavaScript to make it visible).  (You could alternatively initially style the image to `opacity: 0` but then you might also see a non-scale3d'd image for a split second at the beginning, so you'd need to style that initially as well; probably easier just to start with `visibility: hidden`.)

By the way, with your code as written, you also risk the animation occurring *before* the image has loaded (something you might not notice with a fast connection and cached image). If that happened, your animation would essentially be invisible to users. A solution would be only to add the animation class (`zoomIn`) to your image after the image's `load` event has fired. (Ideally you'd attach a `load` handler to the image using `addEventListener()`, but you could also keep it simple and use an `onload` attribute directly in your `<img>` tag.)